# How to access YouTubePlayerView inside Butterknife onlick function

Tags: java, android, butterknife

Using this method is throwing a null object reference. Butterknife wont allow any refrence to view inside the `void go(){` function. Is there a way to access this view  `YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView =  player_view;` inside the function?

.java

```
 @BindView(R.id.youtube_player_view) YouTubePlayerView player_view;

   YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView =  player_view;
    //start view trailer
    @OnClick(R.id.iv_play_circle)
    void go(){

       String vid = video.getVideoKey(); 

       if(vid != null){

           youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
               @Override
               public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                   youTubePlayer.loadVideo(vid, 0);
               }
           });

        }
    }//end view trailer


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView () {

        if(youTubePlayerView != null) {
            youTubePlayerView.release();
        }
        super.onDestroyView ();
  
    }
```

error log

```
E/CustomActivityOnCrash: The previous app process crashed. This is the stack trace of the crash:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.YouTubePlayerListener)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@BindView(R.id.youtube_player_view) YouTubePlayerView player_view;
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView =  player_view;
```

Here you're expcting the value of `youTubePlayerView` to be the same as the 'filled' value of the `player_view` view variable, but in reality, this  assigment is done at the time before the `player_view` has been bound to the view.

That is because the `@BindView` takes effect after `ButterKnife.bind(this)` is called on your `onCreate()`, but your assignment is done on the class initialization.

Either just use `player_view` directly, or do the `youTubePlayerView =  player_view;` after you have called `ButterKnife.bind(this)`.